# Show error details when throwing Validator Exception

Tags: validation, jsf, xpages

I have code in a managed bean:

```
public void setTestProp(String newProp) {
   FacesMessage yourFailure = new FacesMessage();
   yourFailure.setDetail("Really you need to promise to never do that again!");
   yourFailure.setSummary("Stop here, now!");
   yourFailure.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL);
   throw new ValidatorException(yourFailure);
}
```

and in the XPage:

```
<xp:messages id="messages1" layout="table" showSummary="false"
    showDetail="true" globalOnly="false">
</xp:messages>
```

but I get as result message (nicely in the yellow box as expected, not in an error page):

`Error setting property 'testProp' in bean of type com.ibm.sg.demo.Test: javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException: Stop here, now!`

I would like to:

- not have the technical part
- see the summary

What do I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the property resolver catches all *java.lang.Throwable* from the get/set method of the managed beans. The "original" *facesMessage* is replaced with a new one (the previous message is appended).

You have three possibilities:

1. Create your own property resolver
2. Create your own validator and attach it to the field binded to the managed bean
3. Add a validation method to your bean

Hope this helps

Sven

**EDIT:**

*How to add a validation method to your bean*

a) Add a validation method to your bean

```
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent toValidate,  Object value){

    // Do your validation with value
    // if everything is ok, exit method

    // if not, flag component invalid...
    ((UIInput)toValidate).setValid(false);

    // ... create your message ...
    FacesMessage yourFailure = new FacesMessage();
    yourFailure.setDetail("Really you need to promise to never do that again!");
    yourFailure.setSummary("Stop here, now!");
    yourFailure.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL);

    context.addMessage(toValidate.getClientId(context),  yourFailure);
}
```

b) Add your validator to the field

```
<xp:inputText id="inputText1"
value="#{TBean.test}"
validator="#{TBean.validate}">
```

(You can name the method whatever you want.)

This validator has **not** to be added to the faces-config.xml.

Comment: thx for the insight. I can add a validation function to the bean, no problem. Is there a way that that function is called automatically on submission or would I need to play with the onSubmit event (which doesn't exist without a data source) or the code in the button?

Comment: Is there a way that the validation method is called automatically in the bean? Or do I need to call the validation in a onSubmit event (which doesn't exist without datasource). Also a custom validator needs to be in the faces-config.xml. Or can I programmatically attach it?

Comment: The method is called "automatically". No custom validator is required. I have added an example in my answer above.

Comment: Way cool. Thx alot. That was exactly what I was looking for. I presume I could use the this.validators and have more than one function call

Comment: No, you cannot use the validators-property, because EL is not allowed. The property is for registered validators only (classes implementing the validator Interface and added to faces-config.xml).

Comment: Hi Sven, you could use validators when you use an expression validator and call the bean there. The expression validator allows EL. However this is not practical - so you are right with the NO - since it has a different signature (expects true/false in return and doesn't take parameters, so you need to retrieve the submitted value using requestScope.value and you wouldn't know the control. So I'll stick with the validator since it fits my needs. But interesting question (probably a new one): can you update what JSF did read from the face-config programmatically at runtime

Answer (score 1):

Once you determine your field has failed validation, all you need to do is do this, and you'll get what you want:

```
throw new javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException(new javax.faces.application.FacesMessage("Stop here, now!"));
```

Comment: Jeremy -> this is what my code does, just in more lines. The error box is properly triggered but neither the detail shows (only the summary) and the front part with 'bean' is there. Seems like it overwrites the summary, kind of. So problem still open

Comment: @stwissel, your code is being executed in the update model phase even before the page loads that has an item bound to that field, My assumption is Jeremy's is happening during the invoke Application or Validation phase after the page is submitted.  Do you mean for it to fail every time it loads?

Comment: @stwissel is correct - I didn't notice you were doing this in a setter. Don't do that. You want to do validation using a validator, so it executes during the process validations phase. I wrote an article some time ago on XPagesBlog - You can read it here: http://xpagesblog.com/XPagesHome.nsf/Entry.xsp?documentId=982B853206340272852578CB0066C499

Comment: Appreciate the answers!
Toby: it only fails when submitted (it is in the set event). Jeremy: that's where I borrowed the code from. Guess I need to add stuff to the bean... back to the drawing board.